# IE—fullscreen, centered content

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fullscreen

I have setup a site with content region of fixed width and variable height, horizontally and vertically centred, based on the css and html found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers).

That works pretty fine in all Browsers I have tested, even in IE (11). However the page needs to work in fullscreen mode, too and if i run it in ie, the content goes to the upper left corner.

here is my html:

```css
div.wrapper-1 {
 display: table;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

div.wrapper-2 {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

div.wrapper-3 {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: u($page-width);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper-1">
        <div class="wrapper-2">
            <div class="wrapper-3">
            <!-- does all my content go -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

What can I do to make that work in fullscreen, too?

Thanks for help!

Comment: For me its a Program to break websites… At best it is meant to be a browser…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after digging around I could get it up and running!

I added that to my css:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your div.wrapper2 and 3 set a position:relative; This will keep it relative to your div.wrapper1 and should solve that issue. This is also found on the second part of the answer you linked.

Comment: that does not work. The content keeps sticking in the upper left…